# Calculating a matrix of 144x144 using multiple loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem calculating the kuu_s matrix ,which is a size of 144x144; the program is only calculating 121x121 elements leaving the first row and columns to 0, and the last 22x22 elements also resulting in 0.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi

# Define the integrand function
def f0(x,n):
    if n == 1:
        return (1-x)
    elif n == 2:
        return x
    else:
        return np.sin((n - 2) * np.pi * x)

def f1(x,n):
    if n == 1:
        return -1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return np.cos((n - 2)*np.pi*x)*(n-2)*np.pi

def f00(x, m, n):
        return f0(x,m)*f0(x,n)

def f11(x, m, n):
    return f1(x,m)*f1(x,n)

def f10(x, m, n):
        return f1(x,m)*f0(x,n)
def f01(x, m, n):
        return f0(x,m)*f1(x,n)
# Define the dimensions of the tensor
NMHT_0 = 12
# Create the tensor
I00 = I11 = I10 = I01 = np.zeros((NMHT_0, NMHT_0))
# Perform the integration
for m in range(1, NMHT_0 ):
    for n in range(1, NMHT_0 ):
        result1, error = spi.quad_vec(f00, 0, 1, args=(m, n)) result2, error2 = spi.quad_vec(f11, 0, 1, args=(m, n)) result3, error3 = spi.quad_vec(f10, 0, 1, args=(m, n)) result4, error4 = spi.quad_vec(f01, 0, 1, args=(m, n))

        I00[m, n] = result1 I11[m, n] = result2  I10[m, n] = result3 I01[m, n] = result4
a = 1
b = 1
A = np.random.rand(5,5)

Kuu_s = np.zeros((NMHT_0 ** 2, NMHT_0 ** 2))

k = 0
for i in range(1, NMHT_0):
     for j in range(1, NMHT_0):
        q = 0
        k += 1
        for m in range(1, NMHT_0):
            for n in range(1, NMHT_0):
                q += 1
                Kuu_s[k, q] += (
                            (A[1, 1] * (1 / a ** 2) * (I11[i, m] * I00[j, n])) +
                            (A[1, 3] * (1 / (a * b)) * (I10[i, m] * I01[j, n] + I01[i, m] * I10[j, n])) +
                            (A[3, 3] * (1 / b ** 2) * (I00[j, n] * I11[i, m]))
                    )

np.savetxt("matrixkuu2.docx",Kuu_s,delimiter='  ',fmt='%1.3e')
```

the following pic is from mathcad
[image]

I've tried changing the limits of m n i j ,but I get the error of out-of-bound index.
How could I fix the issue so that the program calculates all the 144x144 elements and adds kuu_s to each loop

Comment: The code you've pasted is not valid Python.

Comment: You're running your loops starting at 1.  Remember that Python arrays start at 0.  Perhaps you should store into [m-1,n-1].  Also remember that `range(1,12)` does not include 12.

Comment: Also, `I00 = I11 = I10 = I01 = np.zeros((NMHT_0, NMHT_0))` does not create 4 arrays, it creates one with 4 names.

Comment: Finally, your `k += 1` and `q += 1` should be at the END of each loop, not the start, for the same reason -- indexes start at 0.  Once I fix those 3 problems, I get fairly reasonable output values.

Comment: And you shouldn't use the extension `.docx` for your output.  It's not a Word document, it's just a text file.  And what's the point of generating a 5x5 array for `A` when you're only using 3 values?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim and AKX I'll fix these issues accordingly

Comment: When I had recommended using `quad_vec` in your previous post, the point was for you to get rid of the nested for loops, not just replace `quad` with `quad_vec`. Doing that probably slowed down your code more since I'd assume `quad_vec` is less efficient for scalar inputs, unless it uses `quad` when it receives scalar arguments.

Comment: yep Thanks jared, I've tried to get rid of the loop and replace quad with quad_vec but the code won't run

Comment: @Ayoub In my answer I make use to `quad_vec` as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating `Kuu_s`, you start your loops at 1, when they should start at 0 because Python is zero-indexed. The second issue is starting your `k` and `q` values. Starting them at 0 and incrementing at the start of the loop means they will first be used when they equal 1, but (as I already mentioned) Pyhton is zero-indexed, so you're missing the first row and column. You have two options:

1. Start `k` and `q` at 0 and increment them at the end of the loop.
2. Start `k` and `q` at -1 and increment them at the start of the loop.

I chose to use the second option because I think the code is cleaner that way, though it is arguably less readable.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad_vec


def f0(x, N):
    res = np.sin((N - 2)*np.pi*x)
    res[N == 1] = (1-x)
    res[N == 2] = x

    return res


def f1(x, N):
    res = np.cos((N - 2)*np.pi*x)*(N-2)*np.pi
    res[N == 1] = -1
    res[N == 2] = 1

    return res


def f00(x, M, N):
    return f0(x, M)*f0(x, N)


def f11(x, M, N):
    return f1(x, M)*f1(x, N)


def f10(x, M, N):
    return f1(x, M)*f0(x, N)


def f01(x, M, N):
    return f0(x, M)*f1(x, N)


NMHT_0 = 12

M, N = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, NMHT_0), np.arange(0, NMHT_0))
I00, _ = quad_vec(f00, 0, 1, args=(M, N))
I11, _ = quad_vec(f11, 0, 1, args=(M, N))
I10, _ = quad_vec(f10, 0, 1, args=(M, N))
I01, _ = quad_vec(f01, 0, 1, args=(M, N))


a = 1
b = 1
A = np.random.rand(5, 5)

Kuu_s = np.zeros((NMHT_0**2, NMHT_0**2))

k = -1
for i in range(NMHT_0):
    for j in range(NMHT_0):
        k += 1
        q = -1
        for m in range(NMHT_0):
            for n in range(NMHT_0):
                q += 1
                Kuu_s[k, q] = (
                    A[1, 1]*I11[i, m]*I00[j, n]/a**2
                    + A[3, 3]*I00[i, m]*I11[j, n]/b**2
                    + A[1, 3]*(I10[i, m]*I01[j, n]
                               + I01[i, m]*I10[j, n])/a/b
                )

np.savetxt("matrixkuu2.txt", Kuu_s, delimiter="  ", fmt="%1.3e")
```

You'll also note that I got rid of the initial double `for` loops used for integration in favor of properly using `quad_vec` for evaluating the integrals. There might be a way to get rid of the large nested loop at the end, but I didn't bother. It will only be a problem (i.e. it will be slow) if `NHMT_0` gets very large.

Comment: Thanks a lot; it seems to be working; now I gonna have to validate my results with the results in Mathcad.thanks again

Comment: @Ayoub Does my solution match the result from Matcad?

Comment: the results match, but it starts from column 14 and the entire first 14 lines result in zeros.

Comment: @Ayoub So it does or does not match? If they don't match, is it a difference in floating point precision or actual differences? In your last post you said the integral was wrong when it was actually correct.

Comment: the results match just fine, but then I am still getting zeros in the first 14 lines I'll post another question to clarify exactly what I am getting

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed the spacing problems with your code, plus the issues raised in the comments.  This is the result.  It does produce a 144x144 output array.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi

# Define the integrand function
def f0(x,n):
    if n == 1:
        return (1-x)
    elif n == 2:
        return x
    else:
        return np.sin((n - 2) * np.pi * x)

def f1(x,n):
    if n == 1:
        return -1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return np.cos((n - 2)*np.pi*x)*(n-2)*np.pi

def f00(x, m, n):
    return f0(x,m)*f0(x,n)
def f11(x, m, n):
    return f1(x,m)*f1(x,n)
def f10(x, m, n):
    return f1(x,m)*f0(x,n)
def f01(x, m, n):
    return f0(x,m)*f1(x,n)

# Define the dimensions of the tensor
NMHT_0 = 12

# Create the tensor
I00 = np.zeros((NMHT_0, NMHT_0))
I11 = np.zeros((NMHT_0, NMHT_0))
I10 = np.zeros((NMHT_0, NMHT_0))
I01 = np.zeros((NMHT_0, NMHT_0))

# Perform the integration
for m in range(NMHT_0):
    for n in range(NMHT_0):
        result1, error1 = spi.quad_vec(f00, 0, 1, args=(m, n))
        result2, error2 = spi.quad_vec(f11, 0, 1, args=(m, n))
        result3, error3 = spi.quad_vec(f10, 0, 1, args=(m, n))
        result4, error4 = spi.quad_vec(f01, 0, 1, args=(m, n))

        I00[m, n] = result1 
        I11[m, n] = result2  
        I10[m, n] = result3 
        I01[m, n] = result4
a = 1
b = 1
A = np.random.rand(5,5)

Kuu_s = np.zeros((NMHT_0 ** 2, NMHT_0 ** 2))

for i in range(NMHT_0):
     for j in range(NMHT_0):
        k = i * NMHT_0 + j
        for m in range(NMHT_0):
            for n in range(NMHT_0):
                q = m * NMHT_0 + n
                Kuu_s[k, q] += (
                        (A[1, 1] * (1 / a ** 2) * (I11[i, m] * I00[j, n])) +
                        (A[1, 3] * (1 / (a * b)) * (I10[i, m] * I01[j, n] + I01[i, m] * I10[j, n])) +
                        (A[3, 3] * (1 / b ** 2) * (I00[j, n] * I11[i, m]))
                )

np.savetxt("matrixkuu2.txt",Kuu_s,delimiter='  ',fmt='%1.3e')
```

Comment: Thanks, you @Tim Roberts a lot, Would you explain to me why are k and q iterated with that equation and not just NMHT_0???

Comment: and when I added the real matrix of A the results in Mathcad were too different
here is the Matrix A1,1=0.549 ,A1,3 = 0 A3,3 = 0.193

Comment: the numbers in the principal diagonal elements of the matrix Kuu_s should increase as number of rows and columns increase
it starts at element 1x1 at 0.247 and goes to 31.908 in element 12x12 for exemple

Comment: @Ayoub Your comments seem to imply this question is not answered, but you accepted this answer. Has your question been answered?

Comment: It does answer the question and it does iterate over the 144x144 matrix but, the results I am getting are false that's why I asked

Comment: Because `k` and `q` need to run from 0 to 143, and `NMHT_0` is only 12.  The original code was using a counter that produces exactly the same results.  And to clarify, I haven't validated the math.  I just corrected the issues in the code.  Your Mathcad does not define `a`, `b`, or `A`, so it's not clear there's much we can do.

Comment: The diagonal does MOSTLY increase from upper left to lower right, with a few exceptions.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thank you so much for your clarification